# How do I view my WCF endpoints in a browser

Tags: .net, wcf

I have this:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FloCommunicationHubWebServiceIo), new[] { new Uri("http://localhost:8010/") });

 // Create basicHttpBinding endpoint at http://localhost:8080/Beam.Flo2.CommunicationHub/
 _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(FloCommunicationHubWebServiceIo), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Generic");

 // Add MEX endpoint at http://localhost:8080/MEX/
 var behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true };
 _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
 _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), new BasicHttpBinding(), "MEX");

  _host.Open();
```

Usually I use the svcutil.exe tool to make a WebServiceProxy.cs file and settings for app.config.  Then I use these in other .NET applications.  This usually works fine.

Today I have to supply an address to PHP developers so they can call the web service.  I have no idea what the address of my service is!

I've tried many combinations e.g `http://localhost:8010/Generic` but to no avail.

What is the URL of my endpoint for the PHP application to call

What is the URL to give to the WCF Test Client so I can check the interface.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Added this Error response from WCF Test Client after using suggestions below.

>

```
 Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl 
> If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
> have access,  please check that you have enabled metadata publishing
> at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing,
> please refer to the MSDN documentation at 
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
> Error URI: `http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl` 
> 
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> 
> '`http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl`'.  Content Type
> application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
> `http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl.` 
> 
> The client and service bindings may be mismatched.  The remote server
> returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the
> content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
> 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error URI:
> `http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl`  There was an error downloading
> '`http://localhost:8010/Generic?wsdl`'.  The request failed with HTTP
> status 400: Bad Request.
```

Comment: we need your app.config

Comment: I don't have any WCF code in my app.config

Comment: have you tried from your post or from another machine with different ip adress ?

Comment: If you are using svcutil.exe to generate the proxy, then there must be an endpoint URL/address it's using in either the WebServiceProxy.cs file or the app.config?

Comment: See these related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754923/enable-mex-in-a-web-config or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090569/how-to-define-endpoints-in-app-config-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PHP developers want to use [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) or something like that, WSDL should be published. To do that, just add `?wsdl` to your service endpoint so it should be `http://localhost:8010/?wsdl` and service address will be `http://localhost:8010/`.

You can also override wsdl address by using `HttpGetUrl` parameter of `ServiceMetadataBehavior`:

```
var behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior 
{ 
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = http://myservername:8010/Generic
};
_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

so now it will be available at `http://myservername:8010/Generic?wsdl`

But I suggest not to mix base and relative addresses, so working example might look like:

```
var _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FloCommunicationHubWebServiceIo), new[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9010/Generic") });
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(FloCommunicationHubWebServiceIo), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
var behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
{
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
};
_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), new BasicHttpBinding(), "MEX");
_host.Open();
```

And then WSDL is exposed at `http://localhost:9010/Generic?wsdl`, and endpoint to call is just `http://localhost:9010/Generic`.

Comment: If I try that in a browser I get a blank page.  I get an error if I use WCF Client.  I've put the error in the question above as it's quite long

Comment: I've just updated my answer with working example (tested both in WCF Test Client and the browser).